# Master Method: Divide and Conquer

Tags: algorithms, master-theorem

According to my  evaluation ,the overall asymptotic running time of the  below algorithm is `O(n)`  ,since  `x` (number of recursive calls) is 1, and `y`   ( the number of splits) is 2  , and finally `z`  ( the power   of amount of work done outside of the recursion call) is 1, hence x<y^{d}, but my answer turned out  to be wrong . Why?

```
 FastPower(a,b) :
  if b = 1
    return a
  else
    c := a*a
    ans := FastPower(c,[b/2])
  if b is odd
    return a*ans
  else return ans
end
```

Comment: I  mean recursive calls

Comment: My bad. I'm used to different notation, so I thought you meant the recursion depth is $1$.

Comment: What is $n$ in your question? is it the size of $b$ in bits?

Comment: it means linear time.

Comment: linear in *what*?

Comment: big O notation  of algoritm

Comment: I'm asking what $n$ means in this context. What value does it represent? The run-time is *dependent* on $n$, so we have to first understand what $n$ relates to

Comment: Oh okay, n represents the size of the input.

Comment: `n represents the size of the input` I see `a` and `b` as inputs (`a` seems to be a number, `b` a natural one): how can $n$ be derived from the values of `a` and/or `b`? (It may get tricky if you don't assume multiplication to take constant time.)

Answer (score 1):

`FastPower` will compute $a^b$ using the following recurrence:

$$\begin{equation}a^b=\begin{cases}a & \text{if }b=1\\
(a^2)^{\frac{b}{2}} & \text{if }b\text{ is even}\\
a\cdot(a^2)^{\frac{b-1}{2}} & \text{if }b\text{ is odd}\end{cases}\end{equation}$$

This is $O(\log{b})$ since $b$ decreases by at least a factor of $2$ each recursive call. This assumes multiplication takes constant time since we perform $O(\log{b})$ multiplications.